# Não acho o Web form ASP.NET no Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, aspx

Olá, ao tentar adicionar uma web page com extenção aspx no Visual Studio 2019, não encontro a mesma para adicionar, conforme imagem:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deveria aparecer algo como nesta imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Não existe Web Forms em ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Mas como adiciono uma página como da segunda imagem, to começando a usar o VS agora

Answer (score 0):

Olá, no ASP.NET Core você deve adicionar um Aplicativo Web (Evolução Web Forms):

[image: Criando Aplicativo Web]

Na próxima tela escolha onde quer criar o projeto e então selecione um template (Sugiro criar um projeto usando o template MVC):

[image: Selecionando Template]

Ao escolher um template algumas coisas já vem configuradas e com alguns exemplos, basta rodar o projeto e o verá no browser.

Para entender melhor comece por este curso: https://desenvolvedor.io/curso-online-iniciando-com-asp-net-core, ele é gratuito.

Caso realmente queira utilizar o Web Forms (ASP.NET Framework) no VS 2019, você pode criar assim:

[image: Web Forms]

Depois é só selecionar template Web Forms:

[image: Template Web Forms]